# Function "eliminate selected polygons" doesn't work with PyQGIS

Tags: python, gis, qgis

I have a vector layer (correction) based on a raster layer. It contains some little features and I want to merge those features to bigger ones.
The function "eliminate selected polygons" seems to do the trick when used in QGIS but when I used it in pyQGIS the selected features aren't taken into account.

[This is my layer with the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hvVcg.png)

[This is the expected output, the one from QGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAw8P.png)

[This is my actual output, the one from pyQGIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CLsmI.png)

When I run my code the function doesn't trigger the CRITICAL error.
[The first log is my code and the second is the process without any polygon selection.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Iiajs.png)

Does anyone already have this issue ? Is it possible to use another similar function ?
Thanks in advance

QGIS Version : 3.14 (pi)

OS : Linux Mint 20 Ulyana (Ubuntu focal 20.04)

This is my code :

```
chemin_sortie = "/projet_qgis/pente/donnees_traitement/"
#Input   
correction = chemin_sortie + 'correction' + '.shp'
correction_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(correction, '', 'ogr')
#Output 
pente_vecteur_grand = chemin_sortie + 'pente_vecteur_grand' + '.shp'

#Selection and process
correction_layer.selectByExpression('$area < 500')  
processing.run("qgis:eliminateselectedpolygons", {'INPUT':correction_layer,'MODE':2,'OUTPUT':pente_vecteur_grand})
pente_vecteur_grand_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(pente_vecteur_grand, '', 'ogr')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a function to realize the same operation as qgis:eliminateselectedpolygons. There is still some differences, I think it's related to the order of the polygons to merge. This function is optimizable but works for me.

[This is my layer with the selection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KKOt6.png)

[This is the output with the qgis function with min area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3zFkg.png)

[This is the output of the pyqgis function with min area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eqg74.png)

[This is the output with the qgis function with max area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cEzBC.png)

[This is the output of the pyqgis function with max area](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PMf2Y.png)

This is the code :

```
import types
    
chemin_sortie = "/projet_qgis/pente/donnees_traitement/"
    
# Input   
    correction = chemin_sortie + 'correction' + '.shp'
    correction_layer = iface.addVectorLayer(correction, '', 'ogr')
    
# Selection
    correction_layer.selectByExpression('$area < 500')

# Functions
def get_key(dict, val):
    for key, value in dict.items():
         if val == value:
             return key
def eliminateselectedpolygon(layer, param):
    if isinstance(param, types.BuiltinFunctionType):
        features = layer.getFeatures()
        n=0
        index = QgsSpatialIndex()
        allfeatures = {}
        selectedfeatures = {}

        for f in features:
            value=[]
            n = n+1
            geom = f.geometry()
            aire = geom.area()
            aire = '%.5f' % aire
            aire = float(aire)
            value.append(f)
            value.append(aire)
            allfeatures[f.id()]=value
            index.addFeature(f)
        for f in layer.selectedFeatures():
            selectedfeatures[f.id()]=f.id()
        suppression = []

        while len(selectedfeatures) != 0:
            f_id = min(selectedfeatures.values())
            f = allfeatures[f_id]
            f_geom = f[0]
            ids = index.intersects(f_geom.geometry().boundingBox())
            dict_aire = {}
            for a_id in ids:
                if a_id != f_id and allfeatures[a_id][0].geometry().touches(f_geom.geometry()) and QgsWkbTypes.displayString(int(allfeatures[a_id][0].geometry().intersection(f_geom.geometry()).wkbType())) != "Point" :
                    dict_aire[a_id]=allfeatures[a_id][1]
            a_id = get_key(dict_aire, param(dict_aire.values()))
            a = allfeatures[a_id]
            a_geom = a[0]
            attrs = layer.getFeature(a_id).attributes()
            suppression.append(f_id)
            suppression.append(a_id)
            if a_id in selectedfeatures:
                del selectedfeatures[a_id]
            del allfeatures[a_id]
            index.deleteFeature(a_geom)
            layer.startEditing()
            geom = None
            geom = QgsGeometry.fromWkt('GEOMETRYCOLLECTION()')
            geom = geom.combine(f_geom.geometry())
            geom = geom.combine(a_geom.geometry())
            feat = QgsFeature(layer.fields())
            feat.setGeometry(geom)
            feat.setAttributes(attrs)
            layer.addFeature(feat)
            feat.setId(abs(n))
            layer.commitChanges()
            layer.triggerRepaint()
            value_feat = []
            geom = feat.geometry()
            aire = geom.area()
            aire = '%.5f' % aire
            aire = float(aire)
            value_feat.append(feat)
            value_feat.append(aire)
            allfeatures[feat.id()]=value_feat
            index.addFeature(feat)
            del selectedfeatures[f_id]
            del allfeatures[f_id]
            index.deleteFeature(f_geom)
            n = n + 1
        layer.startEditing()
        for feature in suppression:
            res = layer.deleteFeature(feature)
        layer.commitChanges()
        layer.triggerRepaint()
        return layer
    print("Param should be min or max")
    return None

eliminateselectedpolygon(correction_layer, max)
```

Comment: have you ever written this without using qgis tools?

Comment: No, sorry...
You want to use it with pandas ?

Comment: geopandas would have been great. I found an alternative using R and the terra library which works in very little lines of codes:
https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/457455/merging-small-polygons-with-largest-neighbour-in-r

Comment: Very nice indeed !